# Does IzPack provide an "easy" install mode?

Tags: java, deployment, installation, izpack

I need to provide two installation modes in my installer: "easy" and "regular". In "easy" mode, user doesn't have to navigate thru the steps clicking "next" buttons. He just clicks "install" once and installation proceeds and completes with all the defaults. Does IzPack provide a panel for such a mode, or do I have to write a custom panel? If latter, how do I go about it - any pointers/resources?

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried to make such an installer but I know it's possible to perform an installation once and create an automated installer based on the input.

Theoretically, you could use your regular installer to install your application on a machine and generate an automated installer in the last panel (`FinishPanel`). An XML file would be generated. Then you'd only have to put this file in the same directory as the installer to perform a fully automatic installation on a similar machine (same OS and directory structure, etc.).

Another option would be to run the installer in console mode (run the installation jar with `-console` argument and pass the desired values). It would be fairly easy to create a batch/shell script to do it all in one click. I've tried this approach some time ago and it worked fine. Unfortunately, it seems that adding custom panels disabled this option somehow for my current installer.

The [documentation for these features](http://izpack.org/documentation/advanced-features.html#automated-installers) is not too elaborate.